# requestAnimationFrame is not defined it Next.js with React Native Web (Animated module)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, requestanimationframe, react-native-web

I'm working on Next.js and React-Native-Web. I managed to run them together following the official Next.js example but when I'm trying to use the Animated package from the react-native it fails with Error that the **requestAnimationFrame** isn't defined. Basically this functionality does the node_modules package but I set the alias in webpack to translate all *react-native* requires to the *react-native-web* so even the node_modules package should use the react-native-web.

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

```
ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined
    at start (...node_modules\react-native-web\
dist\cjs\vendor\react-native\Animated\animations\TimingAnimation.js:104:11)
enter code here
```

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the missed RequestAnimationFrame functionality at the server. This error happens when Next.js tries to render the component during SSR.
Unfortunately, there is no polyfill, etc. for such purpose so I just decided to use the Next.js dynamic imports for a Component that has animation functionality.

[Next.js Official documentation](http://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

My own case оust to show how code looks:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const AutocompleteDropdown = dynamic(
  () => import(
    'myAwesomeLib/components/dropdown/autocomplete/AutocompleteDropdown'
  ),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

Now you can use the ***AutocompleteDropdown*** as the standard JSX component

Comment: I have the same issue, and still can't get it to work, because actually in react navigation, the Drawer component automatically loads the animated module, so I can't hack to use dynamic import in it. Even if I don't use the Animated View, it's importing it automatically from the module. So I gotta fake a polyfill for server side and use condition to load View or Animated.View accordingly. But I don't know yet how to fake polyfill node js before codes reach the modules. Maybe in Webpack `next.config.js`.

Comment: Hmm, what if you will create some HOC/Wrapper for your animated component and there you can check if the process is going at the server mode and you will just not render the animated component in the case of SSR? 

To be honest, I still didn't find any way to create such polyfill for SSR

Comment: Thanks, I already did that, I use Animated View or simple View according to ServerSR or ClientSR. But as I said, the Drawer Navigator component on React Navigation module automatically import `react-native-animated` and use it auto, and there is the function `requestAnimationFrame` that does not exist at all, either I'm using it or not. For now, I just check if `global.requestAnimationFrame` exists in `_app.js` and if not, then I set it as an empty function, like a fake polyfill. Cause SSR doesn't need animation anyway.

Comment: It's a nice trick, I'll remember it) thanks @KeitelDOG

Comment: @KeitelDOG thanks for the tip. I'm working on an experimental Expo NextJS project and I faced the same issue.

Comment: @GilsonViana since then I've found the perfect way to handle this, with a RAF polyfill, works great on next dev. But now it's time for me to start testing App codes in production, and when next js build for production, codes can't find `requestAnimationFrame`. Hopefully after 1 day, I understand why and I fixed it. I will post an answer for all of you and future explorers of React Native Web + NextJS.

Comment: @GilsonViana I put an answer that work both on DEV an PRODUCTION, with no need to add anything in App codes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm coding an App with React Native Web and NextJS 12, and in 2021 I encounter this problem and I fixed it, but now I know my fix was only for Next Dev, because it returned for Next Production Build.

Solution details:

- No Dynamic import (which is useful too, but can be annoying when having lot of components using it)
- Using RAF polyfill and Webpack ProvidePlugin.

Main thing to have in mind is that `next.config.js` with webpack 5 is going to check the codes first before even reach next entry points `_documents.js` and `_app.js`. It means that, you can put polyfill in those entry point files, it will still raise error of RAF undefined. You have to make `requestAnimationFrame` ready for config check.

DEV approach that will work on Next DEV only. Install RAF package https://www.npmjs.com/package/raf and In `next.config.js` add codes:

```
const raf = require('raf');
raf.polyfill();
```

This will add `requestAnimationFrame` and `cancelAnimationFrame` function to `global` and `window` object if they don't have it. In our case, it would add it in `global` for NodeJS.

But this solution won't work when executing `npm run dev`. I don't know why, if anyone knows why Next or Webpack 5 act differently from DEV to PRODUCTION, let me know.

**Complete Solution**:

Use ProvidePlugin config of webpack 5 https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/ . Create a file to use as modules, let's say: `raf.js` in root project or anywhere you want:

```
// raf has no use on Server Side, use setImmediate
module.exports = setImmediate;
```

And in `next.config.js` use it inside `webpack: () = {}` like:

```
webpack: (config, options) => {
// console.log('fallback', config.resolve.fallback);
if (options.isServer) {
  // provide plugin
  config.plugins.push(
    new options.webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      requestAnimationFrame: path.resolve(__dirname, './raf.js'),
    }),
  );
}
```

And now, it's up to you to adapt to your existing config logic. By doing this, in Production Build, NextJS is injecting the `requestAnimationFrame` function in Server Side everywhere a module is using it.

Comment: You don't even need Raf or a package for that. Just export your own fake Raf file with `setImmediate` or use `setImmediate` directly on Server options in config. Works great on Production.

Answer (score 1):

### Expo Web + Reanimated solution

Thanks @KeitelDOG to put me on the way.

You should `npm install raf` (requestAnimationFrame polyfill) and **add those two lines to `metro.config.js`** in the root folder. `metro.config.js` does not exist by default so you may need to create it.

```js
const raf = require('raf') // days of work
raf.polyfill() // for these 2 lines
```

Comment: You just saved me a massive headache. Thank you for your 2 days of sacrifice!