# requestAnimationFrame is not defined nest.js/vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nestjs, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to make a ball move in a canvas so I'm using requestAnimationFrame() but once the function is executed, I have the following error :
**ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined**

This is my code :

```
function    moveBall(_timestamp) {
if (ballPosition.x + ballPosition.speed >= 620) // touch the wall on the left
    ballPosition.x = 620;
else
    ballPosition.x += ballPosition.speed; 
SocketIo.emit("rectPosition", rectPosition, ballPosition);
if (rectPosition.x != 620)
    requestAnimationFrame(moveBall);
}
```

I'm trying to make a mutltiplayer game so I'm using socket.io. The following code calls the function (it is triggered by a button) :

```
    socket.on("gameFunctions", data => {
    switch(data) {
        case "resetBall":
            ballPosition.y = 250;
            ballPosition.x = 250;
            SocketIo.emit("rectPosition", rectPosition, ballPosition);
            console.log("RESET BALL EVENT TRIGGERED");
            break;
        case "startGame":
            // ballPosition.y += BALLSPEED; => loop till it touches a wall (end of the game)
            moveBall();
            SocketIo.emit("rectPosition", rectPosition, ballPosition);
            console.log("START GAME EVENT TRIGGERED");
            break;
    }
})
```

Can someone help me with this issue please ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428508/requestanimationframe-is-not-defined-it-next-js-with-react-native-web-animated

Comment: I already checked it, it didn't help me, I don't think it's exactly the same issue

Comment: The main problem is that you are running `requestAnimationFrame()` on the server-side (NodeJS). The server has no UI and as such, no animation frames. (And therefore, it doesn't make sense for the `requestAnimationFrame()` function to exist on the server-side.)

Comment: @Ivar Oh alright, I'm new to all of this so I'm sorry if my issue looks dumb. Thanks for your comment ! So should I call `requestAnimationFrame()` on my .vue ?

Comment: Usually the animations are done on the front-end (so Vue.js in your case). Streaming every frame change from the backend to the frontend might be a bit too intensive. But that does mean that you have to revise your code to move the whole `moveBall()` to the front-end. You then only need to send a signal from the backend to the front-end when some user interaction has taken place so that both/all sides of the players are up-to-date.

Comment: Alright, I see your point ! Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try to do that. :)